# select2 not loading in bootstrap5 remote modal the first time. second time works

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2, bootstrap-5

I recently moved from bootstrap3 to bootstrap5. Select2 in modal stopped working. I know there has been known issue in this which was resolved using

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {}
```

Or using `dropdownParent` option for the select 2 to bind to the modal. But this didn't work for me.

So I am loading content (including modal) via ajax and populate Select2 inside it. When I click the link first time, select2 is invisible altogether. I close the modal and click the link again, it works fine the second time. I tried dame removing tabindex as well as tabindex='false'.

Clicking first time:
[image]

closed the modal and click the second time:
[image]

What am I missing here.

my Ajax code is :

HTML: `<a href='url-to-controller-returning view' class='modal-remote'>Add</a>`

```
$(document).on('click', '.modal-remote', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $modalRemote = $('#modal-remote'),
    url = $(this).attr('href');
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function (data) {
        if (!$modalRemote.length) $modalRemote = $('<div class="modal fade"  id="modal-remote" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-dialog ' + modalClass + '"><div class="modal-content"></div></div></div>');
        $modalRemote.find('.modal-content').html('<div class="modal-header"><h5 id="remoteModalLabel">Loading...</h5><button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button></div><div class="modal-body"><div class="modal-remote-indicator"></div></div>');
        $modalRemote.modal('show');
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus = function() {};
        var $dom = $(document.createElement('html'));
        $dom[0].innerHTML = data;
        $dom.find('link').remove();
        $modalRemote.find('.modal-header > h5').html($dom.find('title').text());
        $modalRemote.find('.modal-body').html($dom.html());
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $modalRemote.find('.modal-header > h5').html('Error');
        $modalRemote.find('.modal-body').html(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Are you using `renderAjax()` to render your html in controller?

Comment: Not really, just a normal render view. But I tried to render ajax and render Partial but no go.

Comment: keep it to `renderAjax()` you don't want it to conflict with other js or css. Try `dropdownParent: $('#modal-remote .modal-content')` or add `<div class="modal fade"  id="modal-remote" aria-hidden="true" data-focus="false">`

Comment: That didn't work either. The only way I can make it work is if I actually write modal HTML code somewhere on the page not generated by ajax.